# how to make flutter app work on ios device

Tags: ios, windows, flutter

We have a Flutter app and we succeeded to make an apk file and make it work on a real Android device. We want to make the same thing on an IOS device. we tried to use the command: `flutter build ios --release` , but it didnt work.

we work on windows computer and the goal is to create a file, send it to an IOS device and and dwonload it to the device.

Comment: You need to have ios environment to build the ios app. You can try using Virtual Box or hackintosh or cloud mac services for that

Comment: Xcode is required to build flutter on ios. xcode is application software for mac. Therefore, you must build using virtual or mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a MacOS environment to be able to generate `.ipa` file for use on IOS device